# Combining -O and -p options in vim

Tags: vim

Consider the two commands:

```
$ vim -O file1 file2
$ vim -p file1 file2
```

The first opens file1 and file2 in two separate vim tabs; the latter opens them in separate windows.

Is there a way to combine these two options as follows?

```
$ vim -O file1 file2 -p file3
```

I tried this and it didn't work. I only ask in case there is a different way to enter this command that actually works.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259558/70524

Answer (score 2):

Answering just in case somebody else stumbles across this question just like I did.

As per the thread linked by muru, combining `-O` and `-p` isn't possible.

I ended up using the following command: `vim -O file1 file2 file3 -c "tabe file4"`. This opens `file1`, `file2` and `file3` in separate windows, then executes `tabe file4` which opens `file4` in another tab.

If you want the tab with the three files to show after opening vim, append `tabNext`, as in `vim -O file1 file2 file3 -c "tabe file4 | tabNext"`.